# App Script error on Contacts import - Exception: The resource you requested could not be located

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

I have a sheet, which has 4 columns A-D with first name, last name, email, and Group. I want to be able to take a list of users on this sheet and add them all as google contacts in one script.

[image: Sheet output]

Each time I run the script it goes through to the 2nd or 3rd row in the sheet and errors with 'Exception: The resource you requested could not be located.'

Any help would be much appreciated. Read a few related topics on the error and calling the new contact ID once created to add the groups, but still not getting any further.

```
 
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  
  var info1 = activeSheet.getRange("A2:D");
  var info2 = info1.getValues();

  for (s=0; s<info2.length;s++) {
    if (info2[s][0]=="") {
      break;
    }
   
      var c = ContactsApp.createContact(info2[s][0], info2[s][1], info2[s][2]);
      var cid = c.getId();
      var ccid = ContactsApp.getContactById(cid);
      var gm = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts');
      var tg = ContactsApp.getContactGroup(info2[s][3]);
      ccid.addToGroup(gm);
      ccid.addToGroup(tg);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought but are you sure you have all the ContactGroups you show in column D?

Comment: Hi, Yes they are groups that already have existing users in.

Comment: About `Each time I run the script it goes through to the 2nd or 3rd row in the sheet and errors with 'Exception: The resource you requested could not be located.'`, in your showing script, where the line does the error occur?

Comment: It varies on either row 18 or 19, last two lines of code. If I remove these lines it works.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `It varies on either row 18 or 19, last two lines of code. If I remove these lines it works.`, I couldn't understand the error line.

Comment: Can you point out which method returns the exception? Not sure which lines are 18 or 19 in the code above. Also, try logging the info you are directly using as input to other functions, since those values are coming from a Sheet cell (e.g. `info2[s][3]`), maybe it is not in the format you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry both, for clarification I get errors on either one of these lines, ccid.addToGroup(gm);
ccid.addToGroup(tg);

Comment: It can vary each time I run as to when the error will occur. What I have done since is split the adding of groups into two separate functions. When split and ran as individual functions they work. But if I run as a single script or use a function to call each individual functions it fails. Very strange...

Comment: So, I’m unable to repro this behavior on my end. I’d suggest the following: Add a try/catch block inside the for loop and a breakpoint in the catch. That will halt runtime when the Exception is thrown and allow you to inspect your variable values, therefore make sure to inspect `ccid`, `gm` and `tg`. My working theory for this behavior is that the `createContact()` needs a delay to allow propagation before calling `addToGroup()`